# Run command if screen exists

Tags: bash, shell, gnu-screen

I have a shell script that is supposed to kill a detached screen session if it exists. The script is

```
if ! screen -list | grep -q "ScreenName"; then
  screen -S ScreenName -X quit
fi
```

Unfortunately it seems that the screen -S ... -X quit command always runs bc when I run the script and the screen session doesn't exist it still outputs "No screen sessions found." When I remove the ! and the screen session is running, it doesn't kill the running session.

What could the problem be? Thanks

Comment: It works for me if you take out the `!`. Are you sure you're using the right screen name?

Comment: The `!` is definitely wrong; it would instruct the shell to run the body if the named session *didn't* exist. When you remove the `!`, run the given command, then run `screen -list` again, does your session still appear?

Comment: Removing the bang seemed to do it this time...but I tried that before and it wasn't working. There must have been a difference between screen names because I can't think of any other reason

Answer (score 4, accepted):

grep has a confusing convention for return codes. It returns 0 when a string is found and returns 1 when there is no match. You should omit the ! in the condition.

Comment: This solved the problem, although I tried it before and for whatever reason that didn't work. I must have typed the screen name incorrectly (it is fairly long) when creating it for testing.

Answer (score 6):

To get rid of the "No screen sessions found" message, redirect the stderr of `screen`:

```
screen -list 2>/dev/null
```

Next, keep in mind that `-X` doesn't work if the session is password protected.

Then, use `-r` to let `screen` know you only want to kill detached sessions, and there's no more need for `grep` and `if`.

Putting it all together:

```
screen -r -S "ScreenName" -X quit 2>/dev/null
```

Comment: I like this as a nice improvement to my kill statement

Answer (score 3):

@Sir Athos answer is pretty good, if you don't want to ignore valid errors, or just want additional ways to do things in the future, you can use this as a reference:

```
screen -ls 2>&1 | grep '(Detached)' | grep -o 'ScreenName' | xargs -I{} -n 1 -r screen -r -S {} -X quit
```

1. `screen -ls 2>&1` List sessions, all output to stdout
2. `grep '(Detached)'` Filter for detached sessions
3. `grep -o 'ScreenName'` Filter for ScreenName and only output ScreenName
4. `xargs -I{} -n 1 -r screen -r -S {} -X quit` Run output through xargs `-n 1` one at a time, `-r` don't run if there is no output, `-I{}` use {} as the replacement location for your argument since it's not at the end, and run your command

Code Sample:

```
evan> screen -ls  
There are screens on:  
        15491.pts-2.x      (08/29/2013 10:43:53 AM)        (Detached)  
        31676.pts-41.x     (08/28/2013 10:55:00 AM)        (Attached)  
2 Sockets in /var/run/screen/S-evan.  

evan> screen -ls 2>&1 | grep '(Detached)' | grep -o '15491.pts-2.x' | xargs -I{} -n 1 -r screen -r -S {} -X quit  

evan> screen -ls  
There is a screen on:  
        31676.pts-41.x     (08/28/2013 10:55:00 AM)        (Attached)  
1 Socket in /var/run/screen/S-evan.  

evan> screen -ls 2>&1 | grep '(Detached)' | grep -o '15491.pts-2.x' | xargs -I{} -n 1 -r screen -r -S {} -X quit

evan>
```